# jquery script runs only if page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a button with the folowing code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs vote up" id="76" name="up"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Bueno</button>
```

the button does not work unless i reload the page, and i dont know why. any ideas?
jquery code is at the beginning of the body

**jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".vote").click(function() 
{
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var name = $(this).attr("name");
var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
var parent = $(this);
var _this = this;
if(name=='up')
{
$(this).fadeIn(600).html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>');
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "up_vote.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,

   success: function(html)
   {
    parent.html(html);
            $( _this ).remove();
            $( ".escondido" ).css( "display", "block" );
  }  });
return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried `$(document)ready( function () {  });`?

Comment: @Litestone `$(function() {});` is the shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() {});`. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: You are missing the ending `}` of the `if`

Comment: Hack! Didn't know that altough I am into this stuff for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the jQuery code is at the beginning of the code (before the HTML) as you state, the DOM would not have been created yet. Try moving the jQuery code to the bottom of the body (after the HTML).

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you're getting an error in the button click event. Have you tried using the live('click') instead? Can you demonstrate the issue using JSFIDDLE?

Answer (score 0):

In the jsFiddle I created, I'm seeing syntax errors - [Original Code](http://jsfiddle.net/53kv698o/)

If I change the code to [Edited jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53kv698o/1/):

```
$(function () {
    $(".vote").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        var dataString = 'id=' + id;
        var parent = $(this);
        var _this = this;
        if (name == 'up') {
            $(this).fadeIn(600).html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "up_vote.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,

                success: function (html) {
                    parent.html(html);
                    $(_this).remove();
                    $(".escondido").css("display", "block");
                }
            });
            return false;
        }; // Removed ) from this line
    });
}); // Added this whole line
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e7qbcw19/ just tried this code, it works on jsfiddle but not on my site.

Comment: Could you post a link to the page or to a jsFiddle that appears to be failing the same way as it fails on your site?